# React state not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that, when it is visible, I want to query an API every 10 seconds. When the component is closed / not visible, I want that polling to stop.

The problem I have is that the polling continues even after the component has been hidden. Whatever I am doing my code is not recognising the newly updated state variable.

```
const DisplayState = Object.freeze({
    DisplayGroupNamesForSelection: 0,
    DisplayLogStream: 1
});

export default function LogStream({ isOpen }) {
    const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(DisplayState.DisplayGroupNamesForSelection);
    const [logEvents, setlogEvents] = useState([]);

    const onStartStreamingButtonClicked = async logGroupName => {
        setCurrentState(DisplayState.DisplayLogStream);
        pollForLogs(logGroupName);
    };

    const pollForLogs = async logGroupName => {
        try {
            const newLogList = await getLogs(logGroupName); // API call elsehwere
            setlogEvents(newLogList);
        } catch(e) {
            //
        } finally {
            // If the component is still open, ping the API again in 10s
            // However, this always evaluates to true
            if(isOpen) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    pollForLogs(logGroupName);
                }, 10000);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            {!isOpen ? (
                <></>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {(() => {
                        switch(currentState) {
                            case DisplayState.DisplayGroupNamesForSelection: {
                                return (
                                    <LogStreamingGroupSelector
                                        onStartStreamingButtonClicked={onStartStreamingButtonClicked}
                                    />
                                );
                            }
                            case DisplayState.DisplayLogStream: {
                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        {logEvents.map((log, i) => (
                                            <sub key={log.timestamp}>{log.message}</sub>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    })()}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

What I can do is a kinda' hacky solution where I declare a variable outside the component and have the continue polling depend on that:

```
let continuePollingForLogs = false;

export default function LogStream({ isOpen }) {
    const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(DisplayState.DisplayGroupNamesForSelection);
    const [logEvents, setlogEvents] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        continuePollingForLogs = isOpen;
    }, [isOpen]);
```

...and then if I have the `pollForLogs` function depend on the non-state variable `continuePollingForLogs`, it does behave as intended.

I know something is going wrong here with how React handles state, but what exactly I cannot figure out. Even when I created independent `useState` variables which I set within a `useEffect` whenever `isOpen` changed it still didn't work. The variable in `pollForLogs()`'s `finally` was always `true`.

Comment: It sounds like a stale closure issue?  I can play with this later but my hunch is that the API calls should be initiated inside of a useEffect with the right dependencies.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I did try having the API call triggered by a useEffect but the issue of the `isOpen` or `continuePollingForLogs` coming back as `true` no matter what persisted. Another user gave me a solution with `useRef()` which works well. I still don't know what exactly went wrong with my original code. My understanding of React's lifecycle isn't the best; if you could explain the issue I'd be very grateful. Also +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong approach when using hooks. I suggest any future reader read Dan Abramov's article and use his `useInterval` custom hook:

https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to create a mutable ref (variable) whose state (value) will be persisted throughout the component's lifecycle. Then, use the cleanup function in `useEffect` to set it to false when component unmounts.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function LogStream({ isOpen }) {
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(
    DisplayState.DisplayGroupNamesForSelection
  );
  const [logEvents, setlogEvents] = useState([]);

  const continuePollingForLogs = useRef(isOpen);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // set ref to false when component unmounts.
      continuePollingForLogs.current = false;
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Can you explain why my original approach did not work?

Comment: Unlike plain JavaScript variables, `useRef` always refers to the same variable (and hence the same value) in the memory on every render and provides a way to mutate the variable as required. The problem with plain variables in React is that, on every render, their initial values are referenced and not the mutated (updated) one.